# Null pointer when trying to get a preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I get a null pointer when trying to set a preference for the Google Play Store. The code below shows preference code for Facebook and Google Play Store. The Facebook code works fine. If I take out the 2 lines of java code for the play store preference, it displays correctly (but doesn't do anything of course). On stackoverflow, I see 4 questions asking about nulls returned from findPreference(). 3 of them are unanswered. :(. Any ideas?

LiveWallpaperSettings.java - OnCreate()

```
final Preference facebookPreference = (Preference) findPreference("Facebook");
facebookPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

final Preference googlePlayStorePreference = (Preference) findPreference("More from developer"); // assigned null
googlePlayStorePreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
```

LiveWallpaperSettings.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings" >
    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/facebook"
        android:key="@string/preferenceKeyFacebook"
        android:summary="@string/facebook"
        android:title="@string/facebook" />
    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/google_play_store"
        android:key="@string/preferenceKeyGooglePlay"
        android:summary="@string/dev_name"
        android:title="@string/morefromdeveloper" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I saw a page suggesting using holo, but that doesn't compile. I think because because the build target of the project is 4.0.3

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/livewallpaper_settings" >
    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/facebook"
        android:key="@string/preferenceKeyFacebook"
        android:summary="@string/facebook"
        android:title="@string/facebook" />
    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/google_play_store"
        holo:key="@string/preferenceKeyGooglePlay"
        holo:summary="@string/dev_name"
         holo:title="@string/morefromdeveloper" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="preferenceKeyFacebook">facebook</string> 
<string name="preferenceKeyGooglePlay">googleplay</string>
```

---

I have a corollary question. In the method handling the click of the preference (below), I compare arg0.getKey() to "facebook" since getKey() returns a string. I cannot compare R.string.preferenceKeyFacebook because it is an int. This works, but I want to know if there is a better way, stylistically, to do this. Perhaps converting arg0 to an int, or converting R.string.preferenceKeyFacebook to a string.

```
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
    if (arg0.getKey().equals("facebook")) {
```

The answer to this is to replace "facebook" with:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.preferenceKeyFacebook)
```

Comment: What is in your `strings.xml`? More specific, what is the value of your `preferenceKeyGooglePlay` string in your `strings.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct code should be:

```
final Preference facebookPreference = findPreference(getString(R.string.preferenceKeyFacebook));
final Preference googlePlayStorePreference = findPreference(getString(R.string.preferenceKeyGooglePlay));
```

Comment: That's better, I'm a bit rusty and couldn't recall how to retrieve strings ... very rusty ;)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have gone with this solution here.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the preference by title rather than key, this should resolve your issue:

```
final Preference facebookPreference = (Preference) findPreference("facebook");
facebookPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);

final Preference googlePlayStorePreference = (Preference) findPreference("googleplay");
googlePlayStorePreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
```